# Will OS request interrupt to device?

Tags: c, kernel, driver, interrupt, uart

Take UART as an example.

When UART received data, the UART device(chip) generates an interrupt, the SW interrupt handler will process this interrupt, ex: read data from HW buffer. This part is reasonable.

For TX case, will OS/driver generate an interrupt to the device (UART chip) to let UART chip know there are some data need to send out?

Comment: This is probably too broad for SO (or perhaps even off topic for SO). Anyway - I have never heard about a UART that **gets** an interrupt from OS/driver. AFAIK the interrupts are generated by the UART - they are not received by the UART. When the driver wants to send data it writes the data to the UART (to a tx-buffer of some kind). The UART may generate an interrupt when the data has been transmitted so that the driver can write the next chunk of data to the UART.

Comment: You may find this interresting: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/270743/what-is-the-uart-tx-interrupt-for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put things easier, here I check Linux 1.0 as the code base.

```
static void rs_stop(struct tty_struct *tty)
{
...
info->IER = UART_IER_MSI | UART_IER_RLSI | UART_IER_RDI; 
// you can see UART_IER_THRI is not here, the TX interrupt was disabled.
...
}

static void rs_start(struct tty_struct *tty)
{
    info->IER = (UART_IER_MSI | UART_IER_RLSI |
         UART_IER_THRI | UART_IER_RDI);
  // THRI is enabled here.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A typical way to handle UART **input** goes a bit further than you say:

When data has been received the UART generates a HW interrupt and the interrupt handler reads the data from UART and places it in a FIFO buffer, often a circular buffer.

At the higher level when the OS wants to receive data it looks at the input buffer to see if there is any data there.

This mechanism provides another layer of asynchronicity and it means that the input data flow control need only block the remote transmitter when the receiver's input buffer is (nearly) full.

---

One typical way to handle **output** is this:

The UART generates a HW interrupt when it is ready to transmit data. The interrupt handler will then look at the FIFO output buffer and place the first item in the queue in the UART's transmit register. Otherwise if there is no data waiting to be transmitted the interrupt status is cleared.

At the higher level when the OS wants to transmit data it places the item in the output buffer and ensures that the UART will generate a HW interrupt when it is ready to transmit, which may be straight away.

This means that the output data flow is only blocked when the output buffer is full.

---

Neither of these actually require a SW interrupt at the UART handling level. The SW interrupt is a convenient way for applications to communicate with the OS.

Comment: For output part, it is not clear for me.1.  HW will really generate an interrupt then clear it? it sounds redundant process. 2. the output buffer means OS buffer or HW buffer? actually, not very clear about the overall procedure .....

Comment: It is not at all redundant. The HW interrupt removes the need to poll the device and wait. The UART generates a HW interrupt to the processor which then executes its interrupt handler. The interrupt status is cleared by writing the next data to the UART. There is no such thing as "generating an interrupt to the UART". By "buffer" I mean software buffer maintained by the OS. The UART does have a buffer but it isn't relevent to this (it is used so that one character can be held while one is shifted out).

Comment: For output case, example, when the interrupt was cleared since no more data to send, 5 seconds later, we have data to send, but (should) no interrupt comes again, does it mean we can still send directly? This means the tx ready status (the interrupt) was recorded in OS driver.

Comment: No, you place the data in the output buffer and configure the interrupt.

Comment: To be more precise, if there is nothing to transmit, the system disables, or masks, the TX ready interrupt, and enable it back when there are data waiting for the transmission.

Comment: @WeatherVane, what's the procedure/operation to configure the interrupt to let UART HW generate an interrupt to OS handler to send out data? Set a register to 1 to let UART generate an interrupt to let OS know, yes, it can send?

Comment: @user58697, in this case, the TX ready interrupt actually keep sending to OS handler all the time, it just be ignored by OS, am I correct ?

Comment: @Mark The UART asserts the TX interrupt any time it has the room. Unless the interrupt is disabled - wether it is at the UART itself (recommended) or at the interrupt controller (possible, but an overkill).

Comment: @user58697, UART asserts the TX interrupt any time it has the room, but OS should clear it since no data need to send. doesn't it cause a redundant loop? ( TX interrupts, clear, TX interrupt, clear ... )

Comment: @Mark The fact that TX asserts the interrupt doesn't mean the CPU _is_ interrupted. If the interrupt is disabled, CPU doesn't see it, and is not bothered to clear it.

Comment: At the higher level when the OS wants to transmit data it places the item in the output buffer and ensures that the UART will generate a HW interrupt when it is ready to transmit ==> How ? I think this is the last question.

Comment: The device data sheet will tell you how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Device generate hardware interrupts not OS-es or drivers.

Generally communication hardware generate interrupts when:

1. It has got some data
2. It is ready to send data
3. It is in error condition.
4. It has ended the commucication (especially important for hardware with internal buffers like FIFOs)

If hardware uses DMA you may have another interrupts as well

5. End of DMA transaction
6. Half of the transaction
7. DMA error

Comment: according to SW programming experience, we usually call write_xx() to send data, but there is no need to wait an interrupt before call the write_xx()